# Why does terraform keeps updating parameter group of rds cluster?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I am using terraform 0.13 and latest AWS provider version and it keeps updating aws_rds_cluster_parameter_group resource on each plan and apply. Any ideas why?

```
An execution plan has been generated and is shown below.
Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:
  ~ update in-place
Terraform will perform the following actions:
  # aws_rds_cluster_parameter_group.data_db_parameters will be updated in-place
  ~ resource "aws_rds_cluster_parameter_group" "data_db_parameters" {
        arn         = "arn:aws:rds:ap-southeast-2:111111111111:cluster-pg:dev1-data-persistence-rds-pg"
        description = "Managed by Terraform"
        family      = "aurora-postgresql13"
        id          = "dev1-data-persistence-rds-pg"
        name        = "dev1-data-persistence-rds-pg"
        tags        = {}
        tags_all    = {}
        parameter {
            apply_method = "immediate"
            name         = "rds.force_ssl"
            value        = "1"
        }
      + parameter {
          + apply_method = "immediate"
          + name         = "ssl"
          + value        = "1"
        }
    }
Plan: 0 to add, 1 to change, 0 to destroy.
```

Comment: Have not found any solution yet. TF upgrade is not possible as I am working on a client account and client doesnt agree. Ignore Changes not a possibility as it will require managing db parameters outside TF which is also not wanted. If there is nothing we can do then we have to live with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those ghosts updates are a known, long standing issue, as evidenced by [this](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/18311) still open, 3 year old issue on GH without a solution.

You can try updating your TF, as 0.13 is a very old version. You can also setup [ignore_changes](https://www.terraform.io/language/meta-arguments/lifecycle#ignore_changes=) and try if this helps. If nothing works, then there is not much you can do about that. Its AWS provider and/or TF internal issue.

Comment: It seems https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/18311 is now closed. However with the latest aws provider I still face this issue.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not specify `apply_method` in TF code, the default method `immediate` will be used.
`rds.force_ssl` is a static parameter and you need to specify `apply_method = "pending-reboot"` in TF code.

Reference: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/db_parameter_group#apply_method

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar thing when upgrading Aurora mysql from 5.6 to 5.7: `log_output` re-appeared in every plan output.

However, the configured value in the default paramater group changed from 5.6 to 5.7 (from TABLE to FILE). I suspect since there was no change, AWS API returns empty, TF state is not updated, repeat forever.

So: In this case removing the parameter from TF code and leave it to the default was the solution.

```
    # plan output example
    + parameter {
          + apply_method = "immediate"
          + name         = "log_output"
          + value        = "FILE"
        }
```